# Can we add a custom provider for Visual Studio Client side library?

Tags: visual-studio, libman

for our dev team we need to add another provider for Visual Studio Client side library (Artifactory).
Is there a way to add this custom provider ?
Thank you
Julien

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a way today.  It is an [open issue](https://github.com/aspnet/LibraryManager/issues/73) but there's been only one suggestion so far (GitHub) and *that* is mostly already covered by using the JSDelivr provider.

The problem is ensuring that the additional provider extensions are discovered.  The Visual Studio component can use MEF (which is VS's preferred extensibility framework), but that doesn't extend well to MSBuild or the dotnet CLI tool.  With so little feedback, no design was ever proposed to address all 3 runtime environments.